# SQL Server query with PHP - special char in French

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm searching for a field in a SQL server 2005 table. I'm using something like

```
$query = "select * from TableName where replace ( replace ( client , 'é' ,'e' ) , 'ç' ,'c' ) COLLATE French_CI_AI = 'Agence française du texte agréable'";
```

I can ask the table to get the name without the 'where' clause, but I can not ask it if I use this specific name 'Agence française du texte agréable' in a where clause

Every other names are working so I suppose that the problem is related to the 'ç' or 'é' character

thank you for your help !

------------- EDIT --------------

thank you for your anwser. I have made another test by removing the ç and é, like this 'Agence francaise du texte agreable'

And I still can't get the infos ! So finally where is my problem ? ... I also tested $query = "select * from Table where client = 'Agence francaise du texte agreable'";

and the var_dump returns resource(4, SQL Server Statement)

and the var_dump of the fetch_array, returns null

I don't understand ... it works with other names :(

---------- EDIT 2 --------------

Found that my problem comes from the fact that I had only one result, and my code did not work then. 
Then changed my code with

```
$query = "select * from Table where client COLLATE French_CI_AI = 'Agence française du texte agréable'"; 

// SQLSrv_num_rows requires a static or keyset cursor.
if (strncmp(ltrim(strtoupper($query)), 'SELECT', strlen('SELECT')) == 0)
{
$array = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
}
else
{
$array = array();
}

$cursor = sqlsrv_query($db, $query, array(), $array);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($cursor, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
```

thank you all for your help!

Comment: utf comparisons would allow for `'é' = 'e'` to be `true`. any reason you're trying to REMOVE accented chars from the `client` field, then compare against a string that contains the very characters you just removed? "take away this apple and replace it with an orange. hey, why isn't that an apple anymore?"

Comment: Can you describe a little more the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have found my problem. As you said that I don't need this, I have made few changes and found that as soon as my query gets only one result, I can not read it.
(see code changes in my first post)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need to remove the special characters at all (ie: the replace() ) why not just just do:

```
$query = "select * from TableName COLLATE French_CI_AI = 'Agence française du texte agréable'";
```

then if you really want to remove the french characters for whatever reason:

$result = str_replace("é", "e", str_replace("ç", "c"$result);

This way you can still replace the French characters and not mess up your query.